# Sending fragments of code from the current buffer to an interpreter in Vim

Tags: vim, ocaml, interpreter

I have been recently using Vim to develop OCaml programs. Emacs has a nice feature: you can select fragment of your code and send it to an OCaml toplevel (interactive REPL).

How can I achieve something similar in Vim?

Comment: I am about to give you sacrilegious advice: Have you thought about using emacs with [evil-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/Evil)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime), which can be configured with GNU Screen, Tmux, or whimrepl.

Specifically, `C-c C-c` sends the the current paragraph to a window of your choosing. Specific visual selections are also possible.

If you need to keep everything in Vim, you can use [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771), where `<F9>` sends any visual selection to a running ConqueTerm. I think the Screen/TMUX solution is more robust, however.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning [tbone.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-tbone) allows sending lines to Tmux via `:Twrite` command.